# How do you change the text color of the contextual Action Bar? Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I am having issue with trying to change the contextual bar action bar. So I have it set it up and its working fine, but I can't seem to change the text color on the top left. I set up a custom theme for the cab, but it didn't help.

```
 <style name="Widget.ActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>
```

My CAB looks similar to the one in this link, but the text color(top left) is black for some reason.

http://androidperspective.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/nexus-4-flat.png

Answer (score 2):

```
        Yes You can do that...

        For changing text color you have to follow steps...

      1) create XML file containing only Textview

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/contextualAB_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        2)Now, replace following line of code with your code.

     Original : 
        mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(mSelectedCount) + " selected");
        Replace with :
        TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contextual_title, null);
        tv.setText("Contextual Action Bar");
mActionMode.setCustomView(tv);    

    You can replace your color with @android:color/white
```